# How to get optimum performance when using 'for update' cursor?

Tags: sql-server

Which is a better choice of update a record in cursor "mode" ?

```
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @Param_Id     
      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN 
                      ...
                      UPDATE MyTable
                      SET    name= 'aaa'
                      WHERE  MyTable.id = @Param_Id  // update the regular TABLE ...
                      ...
            END
```

**or with**

```
WHERE CURRENT OF my_cur // update the current cursor row
```

what is the difference?

(Cursors are required in this particular case).

Comment: Best choice:  **avoid cursors altogether!**

Comment: :( i asked  for question 'a' and you've answered me for question 'b'

Comment: @ pst please forward your answer to an answer so i can choose it. thanks.

Comment: **@Mid787, the code in your question can easily be written without a cursor, and the performance will be greatly enhanced.**  You basically take the query from the cursor definition and "stick it" into the UPDATE.  In the end, just issue a single UPDATE that affects all of the rows found by the cursor query.  You'll see that a single UPDATE of all rows is significantly faster than a loop of many UPDATEs.

Comment: @Mid787, also, I run across many instances where fellow developers claim that `cursors are required in this particular case`.  Their eyes just glaze over and drool drips from their mouth after they see how easy it was after I rewrite it to not use a loop or cursor.

Comment: @km - it was just a sample i know it can be written without cursor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *imagine* `WHERE CURRENT OF ...` would have underlying optimizations for it instead of needing to find the row again for the nested UPDATE re-selecting on a Candidate Key.

The semantics may also slight different -- imagine if `id` was NOT a Candidate Key.

It would be nice to see some results of some real-world tests as it might show a clear advantage one way or another.

Happy coding.